# I need a way to pull values from a text input written in .kv string to a function in my python functions

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, python-3.5, kivy-language

So I've created a GUI for a program I'm writing, and what I'm currently stuck on is the running of the calculations I want it to perform. I've done everything in Python 3.5, with a Kivy GUI build string to create the tabs (using tabbed panel and screen manager). I've got a button at the bottom of the tab to which this question pertains which says "Calculate" and should be taking the values of the text entries and operating them as part of the equation I want them to do. 
Is the

```
.get
```

function going to be helpful in this case for doing this, or do I want to call more like:

```
class TabSys(TabbedPanel):
def calculate_psc_clicked(self):
    #when they click the button which is id'd as "calculate_psc," this function
    #will pull the values and perform the calculations
    self.Cp_entry = self.Cp_entry.text
    self.P_entry = self.P_entry.text
    self.lhv_entry = self.lhv_entry.text
```

The above code is the TabSys class for my build string in kivy language, after it comes the

```
class nyce_meemApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TabSys()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nyce_meemApp().run()
```

To actually run all the code. I don't want to inundate the question with code, so I'll leave it there, and I can put up any other pieces of code that anybody wants (if need be I can share the file).

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually create the calculate_psc button?

Comment: Yeah man:

                Button:
                id: calculate_psc
                text: "[color=e6e6e6]Calculate[/color]"
                font_name: "Arial"
                font_size: 30
                pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
                size_hint: 1, .1
                markup: True

This is in kv language though, so keep in mind that it fits within the larger framework of the build string

Comment: And have you tried specified the Button's `on_press:` attribute? Something like `on_press: root.calculate_psc_clicked()`?

Comment: Should I supplant the current

    self.Cp_entry = self...

part with the on_press part?

Comment: I'm thinking I might try

    on_press: PSC_calculator.something something something

where 

    something something something

is whatever I need to write in for it to calculate, but I'm not sure what would go there.

    PSC_calculator

is the ID of the first tabbed panel item where we find all of this. I think